# Is {xyx | |x|≥1} context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

> Is $L=\{ xyx \mid x,y \in \{a,b\}^* \text {and } |x| \ge 1 \}$ context-free?
>
> If yes, please explain how we can write grammar or create a PDA for it. If not a CFL, then prove it through pumping lemma.

I have tried to apply the pumping lemma with $w = a^nb^naba^nb^n$ as the word in $L$, but without success.

Comment: I have tried for w = a^nb^naba^nb^n as the word in L. Can't prove with Pumping Lemma

Comment: Isn't it regular? For a word $w$ check if the first letter is equal to the last letter; if yes, $w \in\ L$,else $w\notin\ L$. As there is no restriction on y, y can have length $|w|-2$.

Comment: @emmy Sorry, but $abab \in L$.

Comment: @emmy You may be thinking of $\{xyx^R\ |\ |x|\ge 1\}$, which is (somewhat surprisingly when one first encounters it) regular.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $w = a^nb^na^nb^n$, then it is similar to proving language {ww} is not CFL.

In the given language there is no restriction on length of y. So, let it be zero.
Now, for any valid decomposition w = uvxyz, $uv^ixy^iz$ belongs to L.

Comment: I've been trying a lot, that example doesn't work for this problem. In fact, I think pumping lemma isn't solving it either

Answer (score 1):

Assume $L$ was context-free. What can you say about $L \cap \mathcal{L}(a^*b^*a^*)$?

Hint: use closure properties. (That won't answer the exercise, but solve the problem.)