# Is $L$ always context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

> Consider formal language $L$ over finite alphabet $\Sigma$ consisting of all words over $\Sigma$ that have non-trivial period (non empty prefix that is also a suffix). Is $L$ always context free?

Maybe pumping lemma will do? I was advised to try with a word $a^Nb^Na^Nb^N$ but if I pump only second block of $a$ then this word still is in $L$, because it has non empty prefix $a^Nb^N$ that is also a suffix.

Comment: By pumping you can not only add $a$s, but also remove them.

Comment: This seems related to the [$xyx$](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11629/is-xyx-x1-context-free) problem, which did not get a decent answer. However, here the prefix and suffix can overlap.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė, right! I don't know why I forgot about that. This solves all problems, thanks!

Comment: Does the word `algebra` have nontrivial period?  It has a non-empty prefix (`a`) that is also a suffix, but I wouldn't call it periodic.

Comment: @JeffE, I wouldn't too, but yes it does with given definition.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use closure properties instead.

Closer hint:

> CFL is closed against (pre)image of language homomorphisms and intersection with regular languages.