# Is this language is Context-free language or not?

Tags: computability, automata, context-free

Is anybody can help me please to determine is this language is Context-free language or not?

L={wvw | w,v∈{a,b,c}+}

for example:

part of the language: acbac, abcab, bbcbb

not part of the language: abab, aa, abcc

I tried to prove using pumping lemma for context-free languages like that:

I take this word from language w=**aacbbaa**. 
I split the word to 5 parts uvxyz and if I can pump u and y and the word stays inside  language the language is context-free:

```
u-aa, v-cc, x-b, y=bb, z=aa 
after I pump v and y the word is still in language-> 
u-aa, v-cccc, x-b, y=bbbb, z=aa -> 
aaccccbbbbbaa
```

But the answer inside answers section is that the language is not context-free.

What wrong with my prof?

Comment: Same language here: "Is {xyx | |x|≥1} context-free?"
https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11629/4287, where one of the answers suggests the pumping lemma can be used to show the language is not context-free.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the pumping lemma to prove that a language is context-free (see, e.g., [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12041/755)).  The pumping lemma is only useful to prove that the language is *not* context-free.  See our reference questions for details on how to prove that a language is or isn't context-free: [How to prove that a language is context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755), [How to prove that a language is not context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/265/755).

So, one thing wrong with your proof is where you say "if... the word stays inside language the language is context-free" -- that's not correct.

Comment: D.W. , thanks for post.If pumping lemma not works for any part(y and u) in word I can say that langauge is not context free?

Comment: @Michael, sorry, this site isn't designed for back-and-forth interactive assistance.  I encourage you to study our reference material, and if you need more interactive help, perhaps you can find a friend, tutor, or teaching assistant to help you.

Comment: D.W. only one question is this language is context free or not?